# String length is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a value from form input. Save it to var. Get the length of user input. Instead of number of characters I receive `undefined`. Both alerts return the same `undefined`. Why?

```
var aisbn = $('#aisbn').val();
alert(aisbn.lenght);
alert(aisbn.toString().lenght);
```

Comment: a new low has been reached

Comment: At least the title matches the question/solution this time.

Comment: That's embarrassing even to non-English speaker ;(

Comment: Someone might actually find this question useful if they got that error and searched for it.

Comment: 2+ for being consistent

Comment: English is just stupid: length width height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript does not automatically spell check.

Change:

```
alert(aisbn.lenght);
```

To:

```
alert(aisbn.length);
```

Comment: @RCola get a decent ide, it will highlight as error

Comment: I thought about posting my answer as a `lenght` extension to the String prototype, but figured that was too silly.

Comment: would have been pretty funny though

Comment: What IDE would you suggest (preferably  as light as notepad++ ) ?

Comment: @RCola intellij or webstorm

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled `lenght`. It's `length`. Check this out [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), is a code quality tool.

Comment: WOW i have been trying everything correct and nothing worked how stupid im, but thanks for your answer you saved me